# convert an svg path rectangle to xaml

Tags: xaml, svg

objective : Convert an svg rectangle (written as a path) to xaml rectangle and calculate following attributes.

X ,Y ,RX, RY, Height ,Width

Now, for a given sample path

```
<path d="M0 585.9 A9.42477 9.37886 -180 0 0 9.42 595.28 L141.37 595.28 A9.42477 9.37886 -180 0 0 150.79 585.9          L150.79 377.79 A9.42477 9.37886 -180 0 0 141.37 368.41 L9.42 368.41 A9.42477 9.37886 -180 0 0 0          377.79 L0 585.9 Z" class="st1" />
```

any idea around how this calculation can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not an expert on C# nor vectoral conversation. My only suggestion would be: use [inscape](http://inkscape.org/) scripting to convertiong to xaml. But the xaml don't support all of the properties of svg as I know (exmp. non-scaling-stroke).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a `SVG` to `xaml` converter so this is mainly based on my own trial-and-error experience.

You could replace the `d=` with `Data=` and use a [XamlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader(v=vs.110).aspx).
Since `xaml` has a `Path` `object(Shape)`, I'd suggest you convert the `SVG` `Path` to the `xaml` `Path`.

If you choose to go this way about it, remember to include this:

```
xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"
```

to the string - the XamlReader has to read - containing your `xaml` code.
This way you'll end up with a `Path` `object(Shape)`.